# Objects em javascript

Tags: javascript, array, node.js

Estou tendo alguns problemas com Objects ao usa-los em node js , 
preciso de um Object assim :

```
var clients = {};
var user = { 
    [client.id] : {
                    'nome': 'osvaldo', 
                    'sala': 'B1'
                  }
};
clients.push(user);
```

Porém como estou utilizando node , preciso pegar esses valores dinamicamente pelo index( que é o [client.id]), lembrando que os dados são inseridos dinamicamente e consumidos tambem dinamicamente, e o modo para pegar um valor desse object seria:
`user.[client.id].nome`
Alguma ideia de como resolver isso ? o client.id é o ID gerado pelo socket

Comment: Amigo, não ficou nada claro qual o seu problema. E sobre Arrays... o seu código não possui nenhum Array, somente objetos.

Comment: Nossa ... mil desculpas editarei , pesquisei tanto o dia inteiro que fiquei com array na cabeça

Comment: Sem problemas... acredito que a resposta do @bfavaretto seja o que você deseja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você quer algo assim, sem arrays, só objetos:

```
var clients = {}; 
clients[client.id] = {
    'nome': 'osvaldo', 
    'sala': 'B1'
}; // repetir bloco para demais clientes
```

Testando:

```
var dados = clients[client.id]
```

Comment: pra voce ver o que é estar completamente precionado kkkkkk,
estou pesquisando o dia inteiro cara , acredite estou a mais de 6 horas pesquisando , e nada kkkkkk, valeu meu amigo era exatamente isso ...
me salvou

Answer (score 0):

O que você está tentando fazer é usar um objeto como índice para os objetos client, que ficaria da seguinte forma.

```
var clients = {};
var client = {id: 1, nome: 'Lucas', sala: 'B1'};
clients[client.id] = client;
```

Para que você possa pegar TODOS os clientes do seu 'índice', você faria o seguinte:

```
var clientsArray = [];
Object.keys(clients).forEach(function(key) {
  clientsArray.push(clients[key]);
});

console.log(clientsArray);
```